# Exact power of $p$ that divides the discriminant of an algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am doing Marcus problem 21 (b) of chapter 3. The setup for this problem is given in problem 20:

> > **Setup:** Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of algebraic number fields. Write $R = \mathcal{O}_K$ and $S = \mathcal{O}_L$. Fix a prime $P$ of $R$ and let $Q_1,\ldots,Q_r$ be the distinct primes of $S$ that live above $P$. For each $Q_i$ fix a subset $B_i \subset S$ corresponding to a basis for $S/Q_i$ over $R/P$. For each $i=1,\ldots,r$ and each $j = 1,\ldots,e_i$ fix an element $$\alpha_{ij} \in (Q_i^{j-1} - Q_i^j) \cap \left( \cap_{h \neq i} Q_h^{e_h}  \right). $$
> >     Such an element exists because firstly unique factorisation guarantees that for each $i,j$ we can choose an $x_{ij} \in Q_i^{j-1} - Q_i^j$. We then know that the following system of equations has a solution by the Chinese Remainder Theorem:
> >     $$ \begin{eqnarray*} x &\equiv& \alpha_{ij} \pmod{Q_i^j} \\
> > x &\equiv& 0 \pmod{Q_h^{e_h}} \hspace{2mm} (\text{as $h$ runs through all indices not equal to $i$}) \end{eqnarray*}$$
> >     We can now set $x_{ij}$ to be equal to a solution of this system.  Now consider the $n = \sum_{i=1}^r e_if_i$ elements $\alpha_{ij}\beta_{il}$, where $\beta_{il} \in B_i$, $1 \leq i\leq r$,$1 \leq j \leq e_i$ and $1 \leq l\leq f_i$. I have proven that these $n$ elements are independent mod $P$, that is to say that their images in $S/PS$ are linearly independent over $R/P$.

**Problem 21(b):** Call the $n$ elements $\alpha_{ij}\beta_i$ as constructed above $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ with now $K = \Bbb{Q}$. Except we replace $Q_h^{e_h}$ by $Q_h^N$ where $N$ is some large number to be decided later. How do I show that 
$$p^k | \textrm{disc}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$$
where $k = \sum_{i=1}^r (e_i - 1)f_i$ ? I have been stuck on this problem for some days now and I can't seem to make any progress on it. What confuses me is what does he mean by $N$ is some large number to be decided later?

Any help is appreciated, but please do not post complete solutions. Thanks.

**Edit:*** User Sanchez has asked for a definition of the $\beta_{il}$ which I will now define: Recall that for each prime ideal $Q_i$ lying over a prime $p \in \Bbb{Z}$, we have that $S/Q_i$ is an $f_i$ dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Let $B_i$ be a subset of $S$ consisting of $f_i$ elements such that the image of each element of $B_i$ under the canonical homomorphism $\pi : S \to S/Q_i$ is a basis element of $S/Q_i$.

Then our $\beta_{i1},\ldots, \beta_{if_i}$ are ***defined to be*** the $f_i$ elements in $B_i$.

Comment: The statement will be easier to follow if you suffix the $\beta$'s. If I understand, there are $f_i$ elements in $B_i$, say $\beta_{ik}$ for $1\le k \le f_i$ and then the $n$ elements $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are $\alpha_{ij}\beta_{ik}$ for $1\le i\le r$, $1\le j\le e_i$ and $1\le k \le f_i$. In addition I think the $x \equiv \alpha_{ij} \pmod{Q_i^{e_i}}$ should read $x \equiv 1 \pmod{Q_i^{e_i}}$. If it is so, then the "large number $N$" means possibly: $N \ge e_i$ for every $i$ as you are then free to chose $\alpha_{ij}$  with the stronger constraint $\alpha_{ij} \equiv 0 \pmod{Q_h^N}$.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi Thanks for your reply. Yes it is correct that there are $f_i$ elements in $B_i$, $f_i$ being the dimension of $S/Q_i$ over $R/P$. Oh sorry, but looking at my congruences above the condition that $x \equiv \alpha_{ij} \pmod{Q_i^{e_i}}$ should be replaced with $x \equiv \alpha_{ij} \pmod{Q_i^j}$.

Comment: I think Esteban Crespi is right. Marcus tells us to consider the $n$ elements $\alpha_{ij} \beta$ where $\beta \in B_i, 1 \leq i \leq r, 1 \leq j \leq e_i$. For each $i$ we need to consider the $f_i$ elements from $B_i$. Using only one fixed $b_i \in B_i$ we would only get $ \sum e_i \neq n$ elements in total. (I have the book in front of me)

Comment: @HansGiebenrath I agree with you. I see where my mistake lies before. Assuming this, do you know how to proceed with the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Dear BenjaLim, I don't know how to solve this problem. But I would try to argue as in the proof of Theorem 24 taking more care of the valuations of the involved elements. But I don't know if this gets you closer to a solution or if you already have considered this. Unfortunately I have not enough time to work it out myself.

Comment: @HansGiebenrath Please see my answer below, I have outlined an approach to the problem.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi I outlined an approach to my problem below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us work with a fixed Galois closure $M$ of $L/K$, because then discriminant can be calculated via elements of $Gal(M/K)$. The key would be to calculate the valuations of the discriminant in terms of $R_{it}$, a generic prime lying over $p$. The answer will show why a large $N$ is important, although I will not find the optimal value of $N$.

**Some terminologies**

$\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n$ are the $K$-embeddings of $L$ into $M$. They can be extended to elements of $Gal(M/K)$, up to an element of $Gal(M/L)$. We will denote the extension also by $\sigma_i$ should there be no confusion.

$R_{it}$ are primes of $M$ lying above $Q_i$ in $L$, where $1 \leq i \leq r$. For convenience I will not list the range of $t$.

$e_i,f_i$ are the ramification index/residue field degree for $Q_i/p$.

$e,f$ are the ramification index/residue field degree for $R_{it}/p$. The values are the same for any $i,t$ since $M/K$ is Galois. It then follows that $e/e_i, f/f_i$ is the ramification index/residue field degree for $R_{it}/Q_i$.

$A = (\sigma_i(\alpha_j))$. The discriminant $disc_{L/K}(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n) = (det A)^2$.

$B = (v_{R_{11}} (\sigma_i(\alpha_j)))$, where $v_{R_{11}}$ is the valuation for $R_{11}$ in $M$.

---

By definition, we have that $v_{Q_i} (\alpha_{ij}) = j-1$, so for any $t$,
$$v_{R_{it}} (\alpha_{ij}) = \frac{e}{e_i} (j-1)$$
and for $k \neq i$, $v_{Q_k} (\alpha_{ij}) \ge N$ so for any $t$,
$$v_{R_{kt}} (\alpha_{ij}) \ge \frac{e}{e_i}N \ge N \hspace{5mm}(*)$$

This gives
$$v_{R_{it}}(\alpha_{ij} \beta_{il}) = \frac{e}{e_i}(j-1)$$
and for $k \neq i$,
$$v_{R_{kt}} (\alpha_{ij} \beta_{il}) \ge \frac{e}{e_i}N \ge N \hspace{5mm} (**)$$

Here RHS of double star just follows by RHS of (*), and the precise value is not important as long as we know it’s large.

Now look at the matrix $A = (\sigma_i (\alpha_j))$ - we try to look at the valuations of the discriminant. Without loss of generality let's work with $R_{11}$. Arrange the embeddings and the $\alpha$ as follows. For the embeddings, it can be extended to an element of $Gal(M/K)$, and any such extension is off by an element of $Gal(M/L)$. List first those embeddings whose extension sends $R_{1t}$ to $R_{11}$ for some $t$ (note that this property is independent of the extension you choose), and the first element being the inclusion of $L$ into $M$. Then we list those that sends $R_{2t}$ to $R_{11}$ for some $t$ and so on. For the elements, list $\alpha_{1j}\beta_{1l}$ first, in the order you want. Then those of the form $\alpha_{2j}\beta_{2l}$, and so forth.

We wish to calculate $v_{R_{11}} (det A)$. Consider the matrix $B$ where each element is replaced by its value under $v_{Q_1}$, for this is good enough if all we care is to get a lower bound for $v_{R_{11}}(det A)$.

Look at the first diagonal block, i.e. the upper left block, of which on the embedding side it contains those whose extension sends $R_{1t}$ to $R_{11}$ for some $t$, and on the element side things are of the form $\alpha_{1j}\beta_{1l}$. Using the display equations above, it’s clear that modulo some rearrangement, the first row of the block (remember that the first automorphism listed is the inclusion) is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{e}{e_1}(1-1) & \cdots & \frac{e}{e_1}(1-1) & \cdots & \frac{e}{e_1}(e_1-1)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots &\frac{e}{e_1}(e_1 - 1)\end{bmatrix}$$
where each number appears $f_1$ times. The other rows are exactly the same by looking at the display equations way above.

Now look at the $(1,2)$-block, the one immediately to the right of the first diagonal block. On the embedding side it contains those whose extension that sends $R_{2t}$ to $R_{11}$ for some $t$, and on the element side it has $\alpha_{1j}\beta_{1l}$. Let $\sigma(R_{2t}) = R_{11}$. (For simplicity, we will denote an extension of an embedding $\sigma$ by $\sigma$ too) Then 
$$v_{R_{11}} (\sigma(x)) = v_{\sigma^{-1}(R_{11})} (x) = v_{R_{2t}}(x)$$
for any $x$. In particular it means that for a typical element in this block, we are looking at $v_{R_{2t}} (\alpha_{1j}\beta_{1l})$, where we know is large by (**).

Try to convince yourself that each other diagonal/off-diagonal block behaves similarly as the first diagonal/$(1,2)$-block. This means that if you only focus on valuations, AND IF THE LOWER BOUND YOU HAVE FROM (**) IS LARGE ENOUGH, then $B$ looks something like (for simplicity I will use $L$ to mean a generic large number)

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & \frac{e}{e_1}(e_1 -1) & L & \cdots & L & \cdots & L & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & L & \cdots & L & \cdots & L & \cdots\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & \frac{e}{e_1}(e_1 -1) & L & \cdots & L & \cdots & L & \cdots \\
L & \cdots & L & \cdots & L & * & * & * & \cdots & L & \cdots \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So you can see that in the first batch of columns of $A$, you can pull out a factor of
$$ R_{11}^{\frac{e}{e_1}f_1 ( 1 + \cdots + e_1-1)} = R_{11}^{ef_1(e_1-1)/2}$$ 
Doing the same for the next batch of columns and so forth, we see that in the original matrix $A$, one can pull out a factor of 
$$R_{11}^{e\sum_{i=1}^r f_i(e_i-1)/2}$$

Now 
$$v_{R_{11}} (disc (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)) = 2 v_{R_{11}} (A) \ge e \sum_{i=1}^r f_i(e_i-1)$$
Therefore 
$$v_p (disc (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)) = \frac{1}{e}v_{R_{11}} (disc (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)) \ge \sum_i f_i (e_i -1)$$

Comment: I have not read fully your answer yet, but I am so thankful for it!

Comment: What do you mean by the valuation of an element?

Comment: @BenjaLim, the maximum power of a prime dividing an element. For example in $\mathbb{Z}$, $v_2(4) = 2$, $v_2(8) = 3$ and so on.

Comment: so in the case above the valuation of $\alpha$ is say the maximum power of a prime dividing the ***ideal generated by that element*** yes? In that case then the valuation is also the maximum power of the prime involved that contains the element (since in a Dedekind domain, to divide is to contain).

Comment: Also why is it that $\nu_{Q_i}(\beta_{il}) = l -1$?

Comment: @BenjaLim, yes.

Comment: @BenjaLim, I assume that your $\beta_{il}$ are defined similar to $\alpha_{ij}$. Then $\beta_{il}$ is divisible by $Q_i^{l-1}$ but not $Q_i^l$.

Comment: Also I'm confused how at the end you got from maximum powers of $Q_i$ dividing the discriminant (which seems to me is divisibility happening in $\mathcal{O}_L$) while maximum powers of $p$ dividing the discriminant is a divisibility thing happening in ***the ground ring*** $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: No the $\beta_{il}$ are such that they are not in $Q_i$. That's all that is known about them.

Comment: @BenjaLim, Let's consider an example of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, where $(2) = (1+i)^2$. The fact that $v_2(8) = 3$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is reflected in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ by $v_{(1+i)}(8) = 6$ and $v_{(1+i)}(2) = 2$, and that $6/2 = 3$.

Comment: @BenjaLim, okay. I will have to edit my answer in that case. I reread your question and don't really see $beta$ defined anywhere - do you mind adding that?

Comment: I will edit my question right now.

Comment: @BenjaLim, the answer is edited.

Comment: Also technically the field embeddings involved in the discriminant are embeddings of $L \to \Bbb{C}$. We first need to extend them to the Galois closure $M$ of $L$.

Comment: @BenjaLim, good point, my bad. Somehow I thought we were dealing with Galois extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it changes anything though.

Comment: @BenjaLim, I think it matters - actually please ignore my answer for now, I'll think about it again later. I was relying on the fact that the automorphisms permute the primes lying above $P$ and that they can be used to calculate discriminant. Everything should work for Galois extension, but I'll think about it again for non-Galois ones.

Comment: I am getting for the first top right block, its first few columns are all zeros, next batch of  columns all $1$'s and so on with the last batch of  columns all $e_1  - 1$.

Comment: @BenjaLim, sorry that I'm a bit tired right now so let me just say that my answer should be right (in Galois case) up to a transpose. If you're sure about what you get, then just take out factors of $Q_i$ from each column rather than each row.

Comment: Also I don't get really thing thing about pulling out a $Q_1$, in your answer above what do you mean by "in the first $e_1f_1$ rows we can pull out..." ?

Comment: Let me give you an example. You calculated that in the first block, the second batch of columns is all 1s. If my calculations were not wrong, the other blocks in the same "column" are all large numbers. These numbers represent the valuation with respect to $Q_1$, which means that in the actual matrix $A$, the each entry in the second batch of columns of the first diagonal block is divisible exactly once by $Q_1$, and for the off diagonal ones it's divisible by high powers of $Q_1$.

Comment: @BenjaLim, remember that determinant is linear in columns, so if the whole column is divisible by $Q_1$, we know that the determinant is divisible by $Q_1$. If there is another column (say in the next batch) so that the whole column is divisible by $Q_1^2$, then together with the previous column that contributes $Q_1$ to the determinant, we know that the determinant is at least divisible by $Q_1^3$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @BenjaLim, I don't think you can say much about it. You may want to read about decomposition groups by the way.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was redundant, I didn't really need to know about that. Thanks so much for your answer! Though I need to figure out what happens in the non-Galois case. I think we can do this by restricting automorphisms.

Comment: @BenjaLim, so I checked my solution and am sure that it can be extended to the non-Galois case. Take $M$ to be a Galois closure of $L/K$. Consider primes $R_{it}$ of $O_M$ that lies above $Q_i$. Then consider $v_{R_{it}} (det A)$ for each $i,t$. The calculations are essentially the same - for example, if $e,f,g$ are the corresponding number for the prime $p$ in $M/K$ (remember that in Galois extensions, the $e,f$ are the same for $R_{it}/P$ for all $i,t$), then $v_{R_{it}} (\alpha_{ij}) = e(j-1)/e_i$. The precise bound on RHS of (**) are not important as we can make it as large as we want.

Comment: The rest goes on quite similarly, except that when we consider blocks we have to consider elements in $Gal(M/K)$ that moves $L$ - but if $\sigma$ moves $L$ it means that $R_{it}$ can't possibly sent back to itself, and must be $R_{i't'}$ - another prime, so (**) will take care of that.

Comment: Then if we consider $R_{11}$ (WLOG) rather than $Q_1$, we will get that the factor we pull out is $R_{11}^{\sum ee_if_i(e_i-1)/(2e_i)} = R_{11}^{\sum ef_i(e_i-1)/2}$.

Comment: $v_p(disc(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)) = \frac{2}{e} v_{R_{11}} (det A) \ge \frac{2}{e} \sum ef_i(e_i-1)/2 = \sum f_i (e_i-1)$. If you want I will edit the answer above to include the details, perhaps later of the day, or you can try to work it out yourself.

Comment: Please edit your answer for it is easier to see the details in an answer than in a comment. I tried working it out yesterday and am not entirely convinced it works (the way I am seeing it atm) so I too will edit my question above shortly detailing what I don't understand in your question.

Comment: @BenjaLim, I hope there's no mistake this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to my question above but more of a long comment of an approach on how to solve it. Let $d = \text{disc}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$. Consider the ***principal ideal*** generated by $d$ in $L$, denoted by $(d)$. $L$ is now a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. To show that $p^{\sum(e_i-1)f_i}$ divides $d$, it is enough to show that for every $i$, we have

$$(d) \subseteq Q_i^{(e_i-1)n}.$$

We know that in a Dedekind domain to contain is to divide so that if for every $i$ we have such a containment above, then

$$\prod_{i=1}^r Q_i^{(e_i - 1)n} | (d).$$

Taking ideal norms, (noting that the norm of $Q_i$ is $p^{f_i}$ ) we get that

$$p^{n\sum f_i(e_i-1)} | d^n$$

and so $p^{\sum f_i(e_i-1)} | d$. I then guess that in the problem above we need to set $N$ to be equal to say $n \times \max_{1 \leq i\leq r} (e_i-1)$ but even proving that we have the containment above for all $i$ is not proving so easy.